# Javascript document.referrer empty in IE after redirect

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm linking to a page (page1) which performs a redirect the final page (page2). But on page 2 the document.referrer property is empty but only in I.E because of the redirect.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks
Van

--Edit---

Page A simply as a link to Page B. Page B uses window.location to redirect to the url for Page C. But as stated the document.referrer property is empty in Page C after the redirect from Page B this is **only** the case in I.E.

Also - I am only using http not **https**

Comment: How can you do redirect?

Comment: Are you redirecting from "http:" to "https:"?  In that case, the answer is **no**.  In general, the "referrer" property is not *at all* reliable and its use for any important functionality should be avoided.

Comment: Try location.href instead of window.location to do the redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of IE, see: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html
If it's IE, create a new link to that url, then click it.

```
function goto(url){
  if(isIE){
    var referLink = document.createElement('a');
    referLink.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(referLink);
    referLink.click();    
  }
  else{
      location.href = url;
  }
}
```